# Getting type information of C symbols

Tags: c, types

Let me try to give some background first. I'm working on some project with some micro controller (AVR) which I'm accessing through some interface (UART). I'm doing direct writes to its global variables and I'm also able to directly execute functions (write args, trigger execution, read back return values).

AVR code is in C compiled with GCC toolchain. PC, that is communicating with it, is running python code. As of now I have imported adress & size information into python easily by parsing 'objdump -x' output. Now what would greatly boost my development would be information about types of the symbols (types & sizes of structs elements, enums values, functions arguments & return values, ...).

Somehow this seemed like a common thing that people do daily, and I was naively expecting ready-made python tools at start. Well, not so easy. By now I've spend many hours looking into various ways how to accomplish that.
One approach would be to just parse the C code (using e.g. pycparser). But seems like I would have to at least 'pre-parse' the code to exclude various unsupported constructs and various ordering problems and so on. Also, in theory, the problem would be if compiler would do some optimizations, like struct or enum reordering and so on.
I've been also looking into various gcc, gdb and objdump options to get such information. Have spent some time looking for tools for extracting information from various debugging formats (dwarf, stabs).
The closest I get so far is to dump stabs debugging information with objdump -g option. This outputs C-like information, which I would then parse using pycparser or on my own.

But before I spent my time doing that, I decided to raise a question here, strongly hoping that someone will hit me with possibly totally different approach I just haven't think of.

Comment: To my knowledge, the compiler isn't allowed to so `struct` reordering, as this would potentially break binary compatability. (And `enum` reordering doesn't make sense. What would you reorder?)

Comment: True. This is not allowed by standard, as far as I know. But, as in my case, when binary portability doesn't really matter, even reordering could make sense. E.g. compiler could assign 0 to the most commonly used value of enum.
I don't believe any compiler really does anything like that. Just wanted to point out that I prefer post-compile approach. But any ready made solution would be better than to code that by myself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite nice tool called [c2ph](http://perldoc.perl.org/c2ph.html) that dumps a parsable descripton of the types and sizes (using debug info as the source)

Comment: This seems like a nice solution at least for a part of my problem. But it gives me an error no matter if I try *.s file or *.c file. Here is the error if it has any meaning:

bad array stab: (0,71)=ar(0,72)=r(0,72);0;-1;;0;22;(0,11),0,184;; in _jmp_buf:T(0,70)=s23_jb:(0,71)=ar(0,72)=r(0,72);0;-1;;0;22;(0,11),0,184;;
  at /usr/bin/pstruct line 998, <> line 65.

Answer (score 0):

To answer myself... this is what I found:

http://code.google.com/p/pydevtools/

Actually I knew about it before, but it didn't really work for me at first.
So basically I made it Python 3 compatible and did few other fixes/changes also - here you can get it all:

http://code.google.com/p/pydevtools/source/checkout

Actually there is some more code which actually uses this module, but it is not finished yet. I will probably add it when finished.